# Search address by name link - Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

How to get the web address  not by the title but by the description of the link (in this case, "następna strona" it's means next page) with html code?
More specifically draw the internet address of the link name which is between text

```
<a href="/w/index.php?title=Kategoria:angielski_(indeks)&amp;pagefrom=abstract+art#mw-pages" title="Kategoria:angielski (indeks)">następna strona</a>

package outerDictionary;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class adressWWW {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc;
        List<String> wikiWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        String addresWWW="http://pl.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Kategoria:angielski_(indeks)&pagefrom=abducent#mw-pages";



            try {
                doc = Jsoup    .connect(addresWWW).get();

                String title = doc.title();
                System.out.println(title);

                //Element inDiv = doc.select("a[title=Kategoria:angielski (indeks)]").first();
                Element inDiv = doc.select("a[title=Kategoria:angielski (indeks)]następna strona").first();
                System.out.println(inDiv);
                String  row = inDiv.attr("abs:href");
                System.out.println("xxx "+row);    

                // System.out.println(row.text());}
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (String x : wikiWords)
                System.out.println(x);

            System.out.println(wikiWords.size());

    }}
```

Comment: Try `doc.select("a[href*=następna strona]")`, which should get you the example link you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the text of each link:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://pl.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Kategoria:angielski_(indeks)&pagefrom=abducent#mw-pages").get();

for( Element element : doc.select("a") )
{
    if( element.text().equalsIgnoreCase("następna strona") )
    {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

Or using the [selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax):

```
// ...

for( Element element : doc.select("a:contains(następna strona)") )
{
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

In both cases, the result is:

```
<a href="/w/index.php?title=Kategoria:angielski_(indeks)&amp;pagefrom=abstract+art#mw-pages" title="Kategoria:angielski (indeks)">następna strona</a>
<a href="/w/index.php?title=Kategoria:angielski_(indeks)&amp;pagefrom=abstract+art#mw-pages" title="Kategoria:angielski (indeks)">następna strona</a>
```